# Sorting faceted layer charts with certain number of columns

Tags: python, altair

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52882510) answer shows how to facet layered charts in altiar.
In the [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.LayerChart.html?altair.LayerChart.facet#altair.LayerChart.facet), the `facet()` function states to be able to take a `facet` parameter that can either be a `string` or an `alt.Facet` object.

I would like to produce a faceted layered chart, with sorted charts and with columns. My approach was this

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

horse = alt.Chart().mark_point().encode(
    x='Weight_in_lbs',
    y='Horsepower'
)

miles = alt.Chart().mark_point(color='red').encode(
    x='Weight_in_lbs',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon'
)

alt.layer(horse, miles, data=cars).facet(
    # column='Origin'
    facet=alt.Facet('Origin', sort=['USA', 'Europe', 'Japan'], columns=2)
)
```

Unforunately, it raises this non imformative error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    'test.html', webdriver='firefox', embed_options={'renderer': 'svg'})
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py", line 476, in save
    result = save(**kwds)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\save.py", line 79, in save
    spec = chart.to_dict()
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py", line 382, in to_dict
    dct = super(TopLevelMixin, copy).to_dict(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 328, in to_dict
    context=context,
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 62, in _todict
    for k, v in obj.items()
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 63, in <dictcomp>
    if v is not Undefined
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 56, in _todict
    return obj.to_dict(validate=validate, context=context)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py", line 382, in to_dict
    dct = super(TopLevelMixin, copy).to_dict(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 328, in to_dict
    context=context,
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 62, in _todict
    for k, v in obj.items()
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 63, in <dictcomp>
    if v is not Undefined
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 58, in _todict
    return [_todict(v, validate, context) for v in obj]
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
    return [_todict(v, validate, context) for v in obj]
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 56, in _todict
    return obj.to_dict(validate=validate, context=context)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v4\api.py", line 382, in to_dict
    dct = super(TopLevelMixin, copy).to_dict(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<conda-path>\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\schemapi.py", line 339, in to_dict
    raise SchemaValidationError(self, err)
altair.utils.schemapi.SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v4.api.Chart, validating 'required'

        'data' is a required property
```

Without the `columns=2` parameter, it works as expected, but has no columns.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `column=2` property out of the `alt.Facet` object seems to do the job.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

horse = alt.Chart().mark_point().encode(
    x='Weight_in_lbs',
    y='Horsepower'
)

miles = alt.Chart().mark_point(color='red').encode(
    x='Weight_in_lbs',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon'
)

alt.layer(horse, miles, data=cars).facet(
    # column='Origin'
    facet=alt.Facet('Origin', sort=['USA', 'Europe', 'Japan']),
    columns=2
)
```

[image: Feceted LayerChart with sorted sub-charts in 2 columns]