# Altair: Remove title from layered faceted graphs

Tags: altair

I tried layering faceted graphs and it failed, so moved to the method suggested in here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52882510/20390480 which basically layer the graphs and then call .facet(column). With this method I am unable to remove the facet title.

I tried .facet(column, title=None) throws the following error.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

horse = alt.Chart().mark_point().encode(
    x = 'Weight_in_lbs',
    y = 'Horsepower'
)

miles = alt.Chart().mark_point(color='red').encode(
    x = 'Weight_in_lbs',
    y = 'Miles_per_Gallon'
)

alt.layer(horse, miles, data=cars).facet(column='Origin', title=None)
```

```
SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v4.api.Chart, validating 'required'

        'data' is a required property
        

alt.FacetChart(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
alt.layer(horse, miles, data=cars).facet(column=alt.Column('Origin', title=None))
```